# Add existing module to custom twig

Tags: opencart-3

I've been tasked with customising an Opencart site for my employers, and I'm completely new to it. To meet the design requirements, I need to create a div which has a single background image, and contains a footer and a brand banner.

I can customise the footer easily enough by changing the footer.php view. But I can't work out how to add a particular existing module into my twig. I've Googled loads of different phrases, but I only find things about how to customise in the admin.

From looking at the code, I can see from the other controller/views that it is possible to load a child controller like this

```
$data['banner'] = $this->load->controller('mybannermodule');
```

And then insert it into the twig like this

```
{{ banner }}
```

But I don't know how to specify the controller name for the particular banner I'm after (it's the standard one which shows a carousel of brands)- I've been looking through the other controllers, but I can't find one which appears to be the carousel of brans... I think it's not helping that I am confused about how the modules you can add / edit in the admin relate to the controllers and views in the code..

Can anyone help nudge me in the right direction, or let me know if I am just approaching this all wrong...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have it simply show an image from the banners set in the admin end?

If so I would simply as this to my controller

```
$results = $this->model_design_banner->getBanner($setting['banner_id']);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $result['image'])) {
            $data['banners'][] = array(
                'title' => $result['title'],
                'link'  => $result['link'],
                'image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $setting['width'], $setting['height'])
            );
        }
    }
```

Then i would simply call the $result from the twig

You would need to specify the ID of the banner